# Why is the projection to the image of an algebra in the commutator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

The proof in Murphy's book (chapter on Von Neumann algebras) of the fact that a *-subalgebra $A$ of $B(\mathcal{H})$ is strongly dense in $A''$.

The proof procedes as follows:
Take a $x\in \mathcal{H}$ and construct a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ namely
$$\mathcal{K}:=\overline{\{v(x)  | v\in A\}}^{\|.\|}$$

Then define $p$ the projection of $\mathcal{H}$ onto $\mathcal{K}$.

Then the claim is that $p\in A'$. Why is this so?

Wouldn't this mean that $\forall x \in \mathcal{H}$ we have that
$$p(v(x))=v(p(x)).$$
But $p(x)$  might be zero whereas $v(x)$ might not be. Wouldn't be a contradiction?
Or is this impossible.
In either case why would it be true that $p\in A'$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $pv(x) = v(x)$ for all $x\in  H$ and $v\in A$ you get $pv = v$. In particular **since $A$ is $*$-closed** you have for all $v\in A$ that $vp = (p^*v^*)^*=(pv^*)^*=v$, and so $vp=v=pv$.

Comment: I don't see why you use the inner product. By definition of $\mathcal K$ and the continuity of $p$ you have $pvx=vx$ for all $x$.,so $pv=v$.  Since you can apply this to $v^*$ and taking adjoints, you also get $vp=v$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you are completely correct, I've removed the inner product, I don't know why it was in my mind.